# Cast Regular Int to Final Java

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am trying to implement an inner class within a loop, and have come into an interesting situation. The internal class has methods, however, when I try and access the variable, Netbeans gives me a compiler error and tells me to make the int final.

As the int is a looping variable, it can not be final. I have tried creating new variables and equating them to the looping variable, but this still throws the same error.

Here is the basic syntax (in pseudo-code):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     panels[i].printI(new printI(){System.out.println(i);});
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use `final int j = i;` on the first line of the loop then, and pass `j` to `System.out.println`?

Comment: However, if I do this, then the loop would not be able to increment the j, because the value would be locked?

Comment: Quite so. See qqilihq's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why can an inner class not access a local variable that is above its scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a temporary `final` variable to hold the value:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     final int tmp = i;
     panels[i].printI(new printI(){System.out.println(tmp);});
}
```

Comment: This answer provided a good solution that helped me. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 4):

This is the idiom:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  final int j = i;
  panels[i].printI(new printI(){System.out.println(j);});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the array variant, which saves you one line of code ;)

```
for(final int[] i = {0}; i[0] < 10; i[0]++)
{
     panels[i[0]].printI(new printI(){System.out.println(i[0]);});
}
```

Comment: oooo I like that one. Provides mutability without any performance penalty or complexity of a wrapping object.